# cant find data by id in php and mysql through wildcard

Tags: php, mysql

here is the query:

```
 $query = "
  SELECT * FROM cbs_tasks 
  WHERE team_member_id = $uid and task_title LIKE '%".$search."%'
  OR task_desc LIKE '%".$search."%' 
  OR task_cat LIKE '%".$search."%' 
  OR task_priority LIKE '%".$search."%' 
  OR status LIKE '%".$search."%'
 ";
```

Comment: What is your expected output and what is your table structure?

Comment: And what does it output right now?

Comment: Please read about prepared statements in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: what fetching method you are using in PHP to fetch the query.

Comment: concate ".$uid."

Comment: Are you sure $uid is set correctly? Echo the statement and show... die($query);

Comment: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Also edit the question with updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put the OR section in brackets and you will get the desired output.

```
$query = "
  SELECT * FROM cbs_tasks 
  WHERE team_member_id = $uid and (task_title LIKE '%".$search."%'
  OR task_desc LIKE '%".$search."%' 
  OR task_cat LIKE '%".$search."%' 
  OR task_priority LIKE '%".$search."%' 
  OR status LIKE '%".$search."%' )
 ";
```